# Are uncountable nouns affected by these words (some - a lot of - many - much)?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, determiners, uncountable-nouns

It is a basic question but I really need the answer.

I know that uncountable nouns are always "singular". For example we say: Information is good / Milk is useful.

**What happens when I use these words before an uncountable noun?** Which one of the following sentences are correct?

A) Some information is ...

B) Some information are ...

C) A lot of information is ...

D) A lot of information are...

E) Many information is ...

F) Many information are...

G) Much information is...

H) Much information are...

I) More information is...

J) More information are...

I used the word "Information" in the previous sentences as an example but I would like to know a general rule.

Thank you very much,

Comment: ***Some X*** and ***more X*** are singular or plural depending on whether ***X*** is singular or plural. In ***many X***, the subject ***X*** *must* be plural, and in ***much X*** it has to be singular/uncountable.

Comment: Mass, noncount, uncountable nouns are not singular or plural. Only count nouns can be singular or plural.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will always be "is" in this case. The "most", "some", etc. modifiers do not change the singular noun to a plural. Think about it with something more obvious, like "milk".

> Most milk *is*...
>
> Some milk *is*...

"Many" specifically means "a large number of", therefore it can only be used for a countable noun. Therefore, any sentence beginning with "Many information" is wrong.

If you want to talk about uncountable nouns in plural, you have to change the noun to something countable.

> Many **cartons of** milk *are*...
>
> Most pieces of information *are*...
>
> Some sources of information *are*...

Comment: "Most milk**s are** pasteurized.", "Some milk**s are** raw."

Comment: Since you are talking about types of milk, you can pluralize. Some mass nouns are pluralizable in this type of context. I would guess that *types of milk* is a more standard way of saying it than *milks* though. See this other Stack question for a discussion: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111357/can-i-use-the-word-milks-when-discussing-kinds-of-milk

Comment: You could also mention that "Many" is used with a plural, so "many information" is not good English.

Comment: Oh the answer is very useful, Thank you very much,